# unsharp thumbnails after uploading image

Tags: images, uploads, media, media-library, thumbnails

I googled for a whole day and didn't found a solution. I tried a lot of plug ins and so on, but didn't get it.

If I upload for example that image here: https://deermylove.com/wp-content/uploads/question/20190707_shooting_kinka_beach_0350.jpg

wordpress is generating thumbnails which is ok, but the thumbnails are sooooo unsharp, that I can't accept it. I also tried 100% JPG quality in the functions.php but it doesn't solved the problem. I think it's a resize problem. I think it's a bad resize algorithm, but I don't know how to fix that.

After resizing (unsharp, you can see it best in my face):
https://deermylove.com/wp-content/uploads/question/20190707_shooting_kinka_beach_0350-403x403.jpg

Any ideas?

regards
Denis

Comment: What is generating your 403 x 403 pixel image size? Is it a Core size or did a plugin or theme add it?

Comment: that's a really good question, took a look and see this size isn't registered. I have 21 sizes registered, and this isn't listed. Even more currently the only plugIn I have activated is "Stop Generating Unnecessary Thumbnails" so I'm even more wondered, that a thumb is created, but beside this fact, even earlier without that blocking PlugIn I had that issue.

Comment: I would track down whatever is generating that size as it may have filters for quality that are overriding your functions.php quality setting. I'd try the theme first (either look through the code or just switch to a default theme, upload an image, and see if it generates that size) and if not the theme, it's a plugin.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I switched the theme, and after that no 403px sized thumb was created. So I think it's the theme. Do you have an additional hint for me, how to find the right place, where I have to search to fix it in the theme?

Comment: Or is there any standard setting which could be overwritten by the theme?

Comment: Search the theme files for `add_filter('jpeg_quality'`

Comment: sadly didn't found anything I searched for that and only for the words jpeg and quality another keyword?

Comment: I found an option, where I can set 100% but it didn't changed anything. I think more it's a problem of the resize function.

Comment: Found the problem. The problem was the plugin "Stop Generating Unnecessary Thumbnails" because the thumbs weren't there, he created wrong sizes for the images. I thought he will create the right thumbs if he need it, but it doesn't work. Sadly there are so much thumbs and I don't know which to disable. sadly there is no option to create on first use ( on the fly ) .

Comment: I just looked at your "thumbnail" and it looks good to me. Are you confusing 100% Jpeg quality with 100% Jpeg compression by any change? From what I could see, the links to both images you provided are identical to look at.

Comment: Oh, I just read your comment mentioning you sorted it out but I had already posted my comment. My bad!